# how to create sessions in html for login page

Tags: html, session

We are making a student record based project and we want to create a login page but we don't know how to create sessions in html.

We have tried to make to login page using the form and then direct that page to the next page and now we want to implement sessions in our project.

Any help shall be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to create server side sessions, but you can do client side Session Storage, but **be aware that it can be easily tampered**. You should have a modern browser for that:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
} else {
  // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

Now with the above code, you can make use of the session storage for storing the login information.

```js
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
  if (localStorage.getItem("user") != "") {
    document.getElementById("login").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("loggedInUser").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("user");
    document.getElementById("welcome").style.display = "none";
  }
} else {
  // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}

function login() {
  var user = prompt("Enter Username");
  var pass = prompt("Enter Password");
  if (user = "admin" && pass == "letmein") {
    alert("Success");
    loginUser(user);
  } else {
    alert("Wrong Credentials");
    logoutUser();
  }
  return false;
}

function loginUser(user) {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
    localStorage.setItem("user", user);
    document.getElementById("login").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("loggedInUser").innerHTML = user;
    document.getElementById("welcome").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
  }
}

function logoutUser() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
    localStorage.setItem("user", "");
    document.getElementById("login").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("loggedInUser").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("welcome").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="login">
  Please login. <a href="#" onclick="return login();">Login</a>
</div>
<div id="welcome">
  Welcome <span id="loggedInUser"></span>
</div>
```

Since StackSnippets doesn't allow LocalStorage, please check [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/pominewote/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 0):

Here check out the code I used in the past for small projects make it work like you want there are three files the php file for sessions, login page and the login-check file. As stated above in the comment you cannot use HTML for Sessions you need PHP which I use in the code below. But, you can get an idea off what I provided below.

PHP FILE FOR SESSION.

```
<?php

        //Start session
        session_start();

            //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
            if (!isset($_SESSION['login_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['login_ID']) == '')) 
                {
                    header("location: login.php");
                    exit();
                }

            $session_id=$_SESSION['login_ID'];

?>
```

Login page

```
<?php session_start(); 
 include('logincheck.php');?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="form-wrapper">

      <form action="" method="post">

            <div class="form_title">
                <img src="img/form_title.gif" alt="Member Login" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-item">
                <input type="text" name="user" required="required" placeholder="Username" autofocus required></input>
            </div>

            <div class="form-item">
                <input type="password" name="pass" required="required" placeholder="Password" required></input>
            </div>

            <div class="button-panel">
                <input type="submit" class="button" title="Log In" name="login" value="Login"></input>
            </div>

      </form>
      <!--This is commented out because there is no sign up at the moment and forgot password-->
      <!-- <div class="reminder">
        //<p>Not a member? <a href="#">Sign up now</a></p>
        //<p><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></p>
         </div> -->
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Login Check File

```
  <?php
    include('dbcon.php');

    if (isset($_POST['login']))
        {
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']);

                $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users_login WHERE userName='$username' and password='$password'");
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($query);

                    if ($num_row > 0) 
                        {           
                            $_SESSION['login_ID']=$row['login_ID'];

                                if($_SESSION['login_ID'] == 2 || $_SESSION['login_ID'] == 3 || $_SESSION['login_ID'] == 4 || $_SESSION['login_ID'] == 5 )
                                {
                                    header('location: Admin_Page.php');
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    header('location: home.php');
                                }
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            echo '<h2 style="color:black;">Invalid Username and or Password Combination</h2>';
                        }
        }

  ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There's no PHP here, right? It's just pure client side HTML.

Comment: Yes, there is. :)

Comment: No bro, you understood me wrong. I told about the question. The question doesn't ask for a PHP code, does it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't know who did I was just saying why. See I think it had to do with the question and not having PHP like you pointed out. But, since the question wasn't clearly stated I figured I would lend the user with question help and show him what I used in the past whether it was PHP/HTML/JS whatever the case maybe so he can work from that. But, no PraveenKumar I didn't mean you did or anything like that.

Comment: how do we pass data of an input field to multiple html pages using only html

Answer (score 0):

Before creating HTML session storage check for browser support of session . This is very important as different browser has different compatibility

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

Then use HTML storage like this

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("username", "John");
// Retrieve
localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Use this to clear storage

```
localStorage.clear();
```

In addition you can use jquery session storage which is also a client side storage

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```